# ssh access to Puppet Learning VM from third party machines failed

Tags: linux, ssh, puppet

I'm learning puppet and I have installed the puppet learning VM on my Windows desktop. Now I can ssh access to the puppet VM from my desktop(host machine) with putty. But I cannot access it from another Linux machine even I can ping it. Can someone help me to find the reason? Thanks!

```
[root@redhat89178 v62]# ping 172.29.38.89
PING 172.29.38.89 (172.29.38.89) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.29.38.89: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=37.1 

[root@redhat89178 v62]# ssh !$
ssh 172.29.38.89
ssh: connect to host 172.29.38.89 port 22: Connection timed out
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

Comment: btw, I can ssh access the third party machine from the puppet learning vm. 

root@learning /]# ssh root@10.198.89.178                                       root@10.198.89.178's password:
Last login: Wed Mar 18 10:37:58 2015 from 172.29.38.89

Comment: can you check telnet 172.29.38.89 22 from your machine??

Comment: @rups telnet still cannot work. 
root@redhat89178 v70]# telnet 172.29.38.89 22
Trying 172.29.38.89...

Comment: that means either ssh port is not open or block by firewall or ssh service using different port. Ask third party service provider